# Sentinel-2 data: plotting RGB Composite Image using Python3

Tags: python, rgb, satellite-image, earthpy

I am using Sentinel-2 data for Satellite Image Analysis. The code can be viewed [here](https://github.com/arjun-majumdar/Satellite_Image_Analysis/blob/main/Sentinel-2_Satellite_Image_Analysis_with_Python.ipynb).

The problem is while plotting the RGB composite image. "To plot RGB composite images, you will plot the red, green and blue bands, which are bands 4, 3 and 2, respectively. The indices for red band = 3, green band = 2 and blue band = 1." The supporting code for this is-

```
rgb = ep.plot_rgb( arr = stacked_s2_sentinel_img, rgb = (1, 2, 3), figsize =(20, 10) #, title = titles )
plt.show()
```

However, this results into a black and white instead of a colored image (as can be viewed in the Jupyter notebook).

What's going wrong?

Comment: What is ep?  Could the [tag:satpy] library help you?

Answer (score 2):

Your image is colored in that it has three RGB channels. However to get a more familiar look you need to apply gamma correction.

Here is how your image looks with gamma=3.00
[image: Image with gamma=3.0]

I have no experience with low level S-2 image processing so I cannot tell which gamma value to use. I believe that the recommended "true color" gamma value is written somewhere in Copernicus documentation.

**Update:** There is [a 2017 paper by Sinergise](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0034425719300422), the developer of the official EO-Browser application, that recommends gamma=2.2 for true color images.

My answer is not complete without the code to apply gamma correction using Earthpy API. Feel free to post the code as an alternative solution.